# Ldap client on CoreOS

Tags: ldap, pam, coreos

Has anyone setup ldap on CoreOS before? If so, how does one do such a task? I have a cluster of CoreOS machines and I'm trying to hook up this service Foxpass https://www.foxpass.com/ to it for user management. Yet, I can't seem to get the proper binaries to run this.  I'm trying to get nslcd, which I can't seem to fine as a built release. I looked at nss-pam-ldap http://arthurdejong.org/nss-pam-ldapd/nslcd.8 but I'd need to compile that, which CoreOS isn't really capable of nor should be.  Is there a trusted repo somewhere where I can curl a built release?  I was thinking of just using docker but I could think of a way where that could be effective for ldap.

Comment: You could create a one-shot fleet unit which compiles a fresh binary inside a docker container, and then copies the binaries to the base file system. The rest of the unit can then perform whatever additional bits of installation logic are needed?

Comment: I'd have to compile things in a container that has the needed build tools in order to compile.  So I could do a one-shot docker container to compile and then run, but there's no guarantee that that binary will always be running happily in an environment different than what it was targeted for.